# How much does a financial advisor charge in NRW, Germany?

Tags: germany, financial-advisor

I am 24 yrs old, software engineer working in Germany. I was able to save major chunk of my earnings and i am interested in investing the savings. I am interested in Real estate along with certain ETF's index funds and normal shares. Although considering my bank account now, real estate is not possible.

I am looking for a financial advisor who can help me deducing a plan considering the interests. I recently came to know that some banks such as Deutsche bank also offers financial advice if one has an account with them although not sure how good their services are. Can anyone help me with the price and recommend me to some services ? Thank you.

Comment: I´d be wary of financial advice from any institute that also crates financial products (like a bank). Mostly they'll try to sell you their own, probably expensive, stuff.

Comment: I absolutely recommend to invest the money for the adviser. Do not go to banks - they want to sell stuff to maximize their provisions, and not to maximize your savings. Advisors are expensive; we paid more than 1000€, but made much more in return after a few years just by saving fees for insurances and investments.

Answer (score 4):

You can expect to pay in the range of 50 to 200 EUR an hour, depending on the advisors skill and academic background. I doubt that it should take a financial consultant more than one or two hours to give you proper ideas on how to invest in ETFs.

From my point of view, you should rather check financial blogs like Mr. Money Mustache or - if you speak German - something like zendepot. The most important advices taken from these sites is:

- open a depot at OnVista, comdirect, ...
- set up a savings plan, which takes x EUR every month and puts that in a global ETF like MSCI World with a low annual cost of ~0.5%
- wait for the compound interest to kick in

Comment: Thank you perfect, yes I can speak German. I did not know of any blogs or content channel or podcasts that describes about the financial planning and investments from German perspective. Most of them are from US perspective and wasnt much helpful. Thanks, i iwll look into them that are mentioned

Comment: I very much agree with the recommendataion to read up in German language media (and check several blogs/podcasts/...) since you need to know about German taxes and tax procedures. In particular, when reading up about ETFs, check that the 2018 changes in taxation are covered where relevant.